# How to replace the values from other dataset in R?

Tags: r

I have two datasets and what i need is i want to replace the values in dataset1 by taking the values from dataset2

```
dataset1

V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10 V11 V12 V13 
13  13  15  15  13  15  15  14  13  15  15  14  16  
13  14  16  14  15  16  13  16  13  14  16  13  16
14  15  15  14  16  16  13  16  13  15  15  15  13
14  13  15  13  14  13  15  14  14  16  14  14  16  
13  14  16  13  15  14  16  15  14  13  14  15  14  
15  13  14  14  13  16  13  13  14  15  15  14  13

dataset2

V1 V2
13 1
14 2
15 3
16 4
```

So i want to replace dataset1 with dataset2 values

```
Expected output

dataset1

V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10 V11 V12 V13 
1   1   3   3   1   3   3   2   1   3   3   2   4   
1   2   4   2   3   4   1   4   1   2   4   1   4
2   3   3   2   4   4   1   4   1   4   4   3   1
2   1   3   1   2   1   3   2   2   4   2   2   4   
1   2   4   1   3   2   4   3   2   1   2   3   2   
3   1   2   2   1   4   1   1   2   3   3   2   1
```

Tried:

```
for(i in 1:6) {
  for(j in 1:13) {
    ifelse(
      dataset1[i,j] == 13,
      1,
      ifelse(
        dataset1[i,j]==14,
        2,
        ifelse(
          dataset1[i,j] == 15,
          3,
          4
    )))
}
}
```

But i am unable to match the the two datasets. So please help me how to map these two datasets in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `match` ('d1' as 'dataset1', 'd2' as 'dataset2') after converting `d1` to `matrix` or using `unlist`

```
d1[] <- d2$V2[match(as.matrix(d1), d2$V1)]
d1
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13
#1  1  1  3  3  1  3  3  2  1   3   3   2   4
#2  1  2  4  2  3  4  1  4  1   2   4   1   4
#3  2  3  3  2  4  4  1  4  1   3   3   3   1
#4  2  1  3  1  2  1  3  2  2   4   2   2   4
#5  1  2  4  1  3  2  4  3  2   1   2   3   2
#6  3  1  2  2  1  4  1  1  2   3   3   2   1
```

Or

```
d1[] <- d2$V2[match(unlist(d1),d2$V1)]
```

Or another approach would be to convert to 'factor' and then set the levels based on the 'd2' columns

```
d1[] <- as.numeric(as.character(factor(unlist(d1), levels=d2$V1, labels=d2$V2)))
```

For big datasets, it may be efficient to use columnwise operation (not tested)

```
 library(dplyr)
 d1 %>% 
      mutate_each(funs(d2$V2[match(., d2$V1)]))
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 library(fastmatch) 
 setDT(d1)
 for(j in 1:ncol(d1)){
  set(d1, i=NULL, j=j, value= d2$V2[fmatch(d1[[j]], d2$V1)])
 }
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(sample(100:20000, 1000*1000, replace=TRUE), ncol=1000)

set.seed(28)
m2 <- cbind(sample(unique(c(m1))), sample(length(unique(c(m1)))) )
system.time(m1[] <- m2[,2][match(m1, m2[,1])])
#   user  system elapsed 
# 0.092   0.003   0.094
```

Converting the matrix to data.table may slow the benchmarks

```
 system.time({DT1 <- as.data.table(m1)
   DT2 <- as.data.table(m2)
   for(j in 1:ncol(DT1)){
   set(DT1, i=NULL, j=j, value=DT2[[2]][fmatch(DT1[[j]], DT2[[1]])])
   }
  })
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 0.108   0.005   0.114
```

So, if you have matrices, the first method would be fast.

Comment: Hai @akrun thanks for the help. My  dataset1 is 1000x1000 matrix and my dataset2 is 4000x2 matrix .Based on these two datasets which approach from the above is better.